Customize cmap for sns.heatmap

I build this correlation heatmap with Seaborn.
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="white")
corr = df.corr()
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool))
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 17))
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(500, 20, as_cmap=True)
# sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=1, center=0, annot=True,
#             square=True, linewidths=.9, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})
sns_plot = sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=1, center=0, annot=True,  fmt = '.2f',
            square=True, linewidths=.3, cbar_kws={'shrink': 1})
fig = sns_plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig('corr.png')

But I want to change colour pallete:
I want 1 and -1 corresponds for red colour and 0 correspond for green colour.
how to customize such colors?

A simple solution would be to color using the absolute value and annotate with the real values: sns.heatmap(corr.abs(), annot=corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=1, ...)
